# Switching destination in a reconnecting client factory

Tags: python, twisted

I have a client based on a twisted.internet.protocol.ReconnectingClientFactory. I want this client to switch to a different server when the number of retries on the current server is reached; I connect to server1, it fails 5 times, I  switch to server2

I currently have implemented this by changing the destination host and port in the retry function of the reconnecting factory:

```
class Factory(twisted.internet.protocol.ReconnectingClientFactory, object):

    def retry(self, connector=None):
    """ Retry to connect to the host. After the Max retries count is reached, 
    switch to an alternative host if available """

    if connector is None:
        if self.connector is None:
            raise ValueError("no connector to retry")
        else:
            connector = self.connector


    if self.retries >= self.maxRetries and self.alt_host is not None:
        # Try to connect to alternate server
        currrent_host, current_port = connector.host, connector.port
        connector.host, connector.port = self.alt_host, self.alt_port
        self.alt_host, self.alt_port = currrent_host, current_port
        print ("Switching to server: %s:%s" % (connector.host, connector.port))
        # Connector gets new address
        connector.getDestination() 
        # reset number of retries
        self.resetDelay()                

    super(Factory, self).retry(connector)

    def addHost(self, host, port):
         """ Add a second host/port to try to connected to once max number of retries has been done"""
        self.alt_host = host
        self.alt_port = port
```

I call This code like this:

```
factory = Factory()
reactor.connectTCP(self.host, self.port, factory)
factory.addHost(self.alt_host, self.alt_port)
```

This is not satisfying because I have to send to the factory the adress of the second server. I'm looking for a different solution based on a second reactor.connectTCP() call or a better used of twisted mechanics (deferred?).